# jQuery Callback on rendered table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fire a callback function upon final rendering of multiple large html tables with table-layout:auto. The browser (especially mobile Safari) needs a while to adjust and render all table cells according to their content. My callback function should not be fired before all cells are rendered and the table has been fully adjusted.

```
function myCallback()
{
    // do something
}
```

Is there such an event or callback? I have tried firing the callback in

```
$(window).load(myCallback)
```

and

```
$('table').on('load', myCallback)
```

Unfortunately both didn't work...

Comment: call the function in DOM  `$(document).ready(function(){
function myCallback();
}};`

Comment: `function myCallback()
{
    // do something
}
$(document).ready(function(){ myCallback(); }};`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$(...).load()` only works if you call it **before** this element has been loaded, and there's no guarantee for that.

I'd suggest to use

```
$(document).ready(callback);
```

This assures that the DOM-tree is ready, only images etc. might not be loaded yet.

(Or you could try to include it in html: `<table onload="javascript:myCallback()"></table>`.)